# How can I upload multiple videos to BitChute?

Tags: video

How can I upload multiple videos to BitChute, rather than each one individually?

Comment: Please follow the guidance of [What can I do when getting “This question body does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/289691)